# *word-wrap: break-word* and/or *overflow-x: scroll* not working inside flex item

Tags: html, css, flexbox, overflow, word-wrap

I'm trying to make the paragraphs in .log_area to break the words and not overflow the entire page, to avoid the horizontal **page** scroll (If needed, horizontal scroll in the .log_area are accepted).

The statement 'word-wrap: break-word;' is not working. Also the 'overflow-x: scroll;' is not working too.

When I disable the flex container, this works. But I need the flex container.

How can I make this work?

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>

.content {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.flexitem1 {
    background-color: #DDF;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.flexitem2 {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.log_area {
    height: 250px;
    background-color: #CFC;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}

.log_item {
    word-wrap: break-word;
}

</style>

</head>

<body>

<div class='content'>
    <div class='flexitem1'>
        <p>Flex item div 1. It's ok.</p>
    </div>
    <div class='flexitem2'>
        <div class="log_area">
        <p class="log_item">First paragraph.</p>
        <p class="log_item">Second paragraph: it's so loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooonnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnngggggggggggggggggggggggggg</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I wouldn't expect words to break when overflow-x is auto or scroll, I would expect the div to expand and then scroll - otherwise 1 it either would never scroll or 2 the word would never break - I don't see how you expect them both to work together

Comment: add `width: 100%;` on your `.flexItem2` css

Answer (score 1):

You are using `word-wrap: break-word`! This is one long word so you should use `word-break: break-all` if you don't want the word to break then use `word-break: keep-all` and it will break the space between the words if you don't want some spaces to break use `&nbsp;`.

I added both examples in my code below.

> Try to change `word-break: break-all` to `keep-all`.

```css
.content {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.flexitem1 {
    background-color: #DDF;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.flexitem2 {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.log_area {
    height: 250px;
    background-color: #CFC;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}

.log_item {
    word-break: keep-all;
}

.long_word {
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<div class='content'>
    <div class='flexitem1'>
        <p>Flex item div 1. It's ok.</p>
    </div>
    <div class='flexitem2'>
        <div class="log_area">
        <p class="log_item">First paragraph.</p>
        <p class="log_item">Second paragraph: Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
          
          <p class="long_word">Second paragraph: This is longgggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add overflow:hidden.

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>

.content {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.flexitem1 {
    background-color: #DDF;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.flexitem2 {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.log_area {
    height: 250px;
    background-color: #CFC;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}

.log_item {
    word-wrap: break-word;
}

</style>

</head>

<body>

<div class='content'>
    <div class='flexitem1'>
        <p>Flex item div 1. It's ok.</p>
    </div>
    <div class='flexitem2'>
        <div class="log_area">
        <p class="log_item">First paragraph.</p>
        <p class="log_item">Second paragraph: it's so loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooonnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnngggggggggggggggggggggggggg</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```